# Datameer - Add Columns to Joined table

Tags: hadoop, analytics

I have joined some data from HDFS with some data from an Oracle DW, which is working fine, but I cant seem to add any new columns to this sheet. To add columns for calculated fields etc I have to duplicate the sheet and do it there - this doesn't seem overly efficient.

Am I doing something wrong here or can you not add columns to a join result sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but I cant seem to add any new columns to this sheet.

Right. It will not be possible to add columns to a `JoinedSheet`. It is a new data set [containing columns from two or more sheets based on a key column which you defined](https://documentation.datameer.com/documentation/display/DAS60/Joining+Data).

> ... or can you not add columns to a join result sheet?

It will be necessary to reference these data as input for a new Worksheet by [Duplicating Worksheet](https://documentation.datameer.com/documentation/display/DAS60/Working+with+Workbooks#WorkingwithWorkbooks-Duplicatingsheetsinaworkbook).

Comment: Thanks, made sense when I went through it, just seemed a bit enifficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using datameer rest-api. You can get the content of the workbook in json format and add columns manually or by implementing a simple script, then update the workbook with changed json file.